In ECHARTS how to setOptions for a specific serie (selecting it by name name)
I got some series in a ECHARTS graph.
Now talking about the y axis it's like this
yAxis: [
    {
        scale: true,
        splitArea: { show: true, },
    },
    {
        scale: true,
        gridIndex: 0,
        splitNumber: 2,
        axisLabel: { show: false, },
        axisLine: { show: false, },
        axisTick: { show: true, },
        splitLine: { show: false, },
        max: 8,
    },
    { scale: true, splitArea: { show: true, }, },
]

and series are like this
series: [
    {
        name: 'A',
        type: 'line',
        lineStyle: { width: 4, },
        showSymbol: false,
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        type: 'line',
    },
    {
        name: 'serie_x',
        type: 'line',
        xAxisIndex: 0,
        yAxisIndex: 0,
        data: dynamicCalculator(),
        smooth: true,
        large: true,
    },
]

Now, if I want to change series symbolSize the command is setOption.
But if I do like this to change exactly serie_x
chart.setOption({
    series: [{
        name : 'serie_x',
        symbolSize: isChecked ? 5 : 1,
    }]

the first serier seems to change name, so the command has to be
chart.setOption({},{},{
    series: [{
        name : 'serie_x',
        symbolSize: isChecked ? 5 : 1,
    }]

adding 2 empty elements before the serie needed.
Now see the problem. The real question:
If there's a dynamic number of series how to setOption on the serie where the name it's serie_x??

series.name is not guaranteed to be unique, but series.id is.
So you can target a specific series by "id" instead of "name" and update its data without worrying how many other series exist. Example

Yes I think I was wrong with the variable initialization in javascript. There are more then one checkbox in the code and was reinitializated. It was good also serie "name" if it's unique instead of "id". This question it's quite useless because it is due to my mistake. It could have changed. I was a little tired. tnx @ned
